# Problem with <a> tags in HTML + CSS styling

Tags: html, css

When you use the `<a>` tag it defaults your linked text with an underline, so naturally I thought you used `font-style:normal;` but it doesn't seem to be working for me anymore, maybe it's my version of Firefox or Firebug???

Here's my current source code, the simplest test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test dummy</title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <a style="font-style:normal;" href="login_page/login.html">Login</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately this code does not work either, Login appears underlined.

**EDIT:** The original author meant `underline` but wrote `italics`

Comment: "when you use the `<a>` tag it defaults your linked text into italics" **No, it does not.**

Comment: It does underline it, however. Maybe he meant that? idk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean underline, then the correct way to take the underline off would be:

`<a style="text-decoration: none;" href="login_page/login.html">Login</a>`

Comment: thanks I realized a couple of minutes ago I feel stupid, 5th coffee today it's what happens.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `text-decoration:none;` in your stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS so you can decrease the amount of code being pushed through the browser, I would use the following code:

```
<body> 
<a href="somewhere.html">Somewhere</a> 
<a href="someotherplace.html">Some other place</a> 
</body>
```

Inside your css:

```
a{ 
text-decoration: none; 
} 
a:hover{ /* For when your mouse hovers over the element */ 
text-decoration: underline; 
} 
a:visited{ /* For links that are in the browser history (Previously visited) */ text-decoration: none; 
color: purple; 
} 
a:active{ /* For links that you are clicking on */ 
text-decoration: none; 
color: blue; 
}
```

Now, every a tag in your document will have the same properties.

Answer (score 0):

Set the text-decoration property to none, like this :

```
text-decoration: none;
```